# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while FOR cycle

Tags: c

Here it is the code on C:

here it is the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct worker
{
    char firstName;
    char lastName;
    char middleName;
    int age;
    float height;
};

void enterData();
void displayData();
void makeCalc();

struct worker *b;
int count;

int main(void)
{
    enterData();
    displayData();
    makeCalc();
    free(b);
    return 0;
}

void enterData()
{
    char firstName;
    char lastName;
    char middleName;
    int age;
    float height;


    printf("Количество работников: \n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    if(count <= 0){
        exit(0);
    }

    b = (struct worker *)malloc(count*sizeof(struct worker));


    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        printf("Введите имя, фамилию, отчестве, возраст и рост через пробел: \n");
        scanf("%s%s%s%d%f", &firstName, &lastName, &middleName, &age, &height);
        struct worker a = (struct worker) {firstName, lastName, middleName, age, height};
        b[i] = a;
    }

}
```

While runtime in this part if program is showed `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`:

```
for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
            printf("Enter name, surname and middle name: \n");
            scanf("%s%s%s%d%f", &firstName, &lastName, &middleName, &age, &height);
            struct worker a = (struct worker) {firstName, lastName, middleName, age, height};
            b[i] = a;
```

What could be the reason of this? I am new to C;

P.S I am using GCC compiler on ubuntu 12.04. and common text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using char type in declaration and using `%s` in scanf

These have to be changed to hold strings

```
 char firstName;
 char lastName;
 char middleName;
```

should be changed to

```
char firstName[MAX]; //where MAX is any convenient high value.
char lastName[MAX];
char middleName[MAX];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is your problem:

```
    scanf("%s%s%s%d%f", &firstName, &lastName, &middleName, &age, &height);
```

You scan in strings, but your variables are only chars:

```
   char firstName;
   char lastName;
   char middleName;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to provide a *buffer* for your data:

```
char firstName[SOME_BIG_ENOUGH_SIZE];
```

rather than a single character:

```
char firstName;
```